# YouTube Red background playing in third party apps on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Is it possible to play youtube content in the background both in android and iOS apps for Youtube Red users. I have not found any official documentation regarding allowing Youtube Red users to play youtube content in third party apps. I have just found this unanswered SO post
[YouTube Red members login api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299693/youtube-red-members-login-api)

And this one which is answered but does not have any reference to any official source explicitly stating that this is not possible
[Using YouTube Player API, play video as a specific user, applying YouTube Red subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604832/using-youtube-player-api-play-video-as-a-specific-user-applying-youtube-red-su)